# Subscribe to a simple ros node in rqt

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I'm trying to subscribe to a very simple ros topic from within an rqt plugin. It seems like the subscription works, but my Callback function does not get called.

```
Subscription::Subscription(QString topic)
{ 
   ROS_INFO("Subscribing to topic: [%s]", topic.toLocal8Bit().constData() );

   sub = n.subscribe(topic.toLocal8Bit().constData(), 1000, &Subscription::chatterCallback, this);
}


void Subscription::chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
   ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str() );

   emit messageReceived(msg->data.c_str() );
}
```

This should actually be very simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was creating my own `ros::NodeHandle`, when I should have used the one I get from `rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin()::getNodeHandle()`.